# Marklogic Query Manager Search to return specific elements instead of entire document

Tags: search, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way for the QueryManager in Marklogic Search API to retrieve specific elements in the matched document instead of returning entire document. Any documentation or point out to any solutions can certainly help. Can any one help on this ??

Answer (score 1):

The query options can specify an XPath extraction to extract nodes from a matched document.

To extract the nodes without a summary, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_40913

To get the extracted nodes as part of a summary, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_90087

Hoping that helps,